# Does Bitninja have sql injection false positives?

Tags: php, security, sql-injection, firewall

I'm trying to save some php code to have saved examples and code templates on a server I currently rent. The problem is when I send $ to the server, it saves it in the database, no problem. But when I query the data it tells me there's an sql injection and blocks the IP address where I queried the table.
Funny thing is that my table has categories and the problem only occurs when I query "category_id=3", the other categories have no hickups showing me the data with $.
Overall, I realize how this could be a problem, but all my inputs are escaped and have special measures in special cases and all my queries are formed by the same functions.

I tried changing $ to &dollar ; to get around this problem so that in the event I forgot to escape something or I don't know, php wouldn't recognize it as a variable but the result is the same.
I really don't get why this could be a major issue with BitNinja when I save html entities in plain text.
I know I could save the codes in files, getting around the database or base64 the code and save it as such, but that's not the issue here.

Comment: I don't use Bitninja and I don't know how it detects or reports SQL injection risks. It's possible it has false positives. In general, using query parameters is a safer — and *easier* — method of protecting your code from SQL injection risks. Maybe Bitninja is trying to get you to use parameterized queries instead of escaping.

Comment: Regardless, there's little anyone here can do to comment on how safe your code is or whether it's a legitimate warning or a false positive, because you haven't shown the code that Bitninja says is at risk.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the WAF module, then yes, it does produce false positives (as would almost any WAF detection of SQL injections).  In their [blog entry](https://bitninja.io/blog/2018/08/31/most-famous-vulnerabilities-sql-injection) about this they state:

> Our WAF 2.0 module protects you against SQL injections.
>
> In the official OWASP Core Ruleset we have a ruleset for this attack
>   vector. This is an very general ruleset so if you need to use it you
>   must be very careful. I suggest if you enable it, use it in log-only
>   mode.

As Bill mentions in the comments, we would need to see the code and data, to determine whether this is a true false positive.